# Solr: Use field value from invoking document inside of scale()

Tags: solr, lucene

Is it possible to use a field value of the invoking document inside the function scale()?

I tried the following:

```
...select?q=*:*&param=field_of_document&fl=$param,pseudo_field:scale(if(...$param...), 0,1000)
```

Although the first $param returns the value of *field_of_document* of the result set's individual documents, the second $param (the one inside scale() ) is evaluated for each document of the whole index again as if I used *field_of_document* directly.

Again the question: Is there a chance to "inject" a field value of the "outer" document into the scale-function's parameters?

Comment: Can't you just use the name of the field you want to refer to? Like in the sum example [here](http://solr.pl/en/2011/11/22/solr-4-0-new-fl-parameter-functionalities-first-look/).

Comment: No, I can't, because that would make it even worse. It is the nature of scale() that all field references are interpreted against each document of the whole index (table scan). To be exact: scale() does it once again the invoking document and then against the whole index to get the minimum and maximum of the whole set. Afterwards it "scales" the document-value into the min/max range of the index. What I want is, I want to use the one document value also within the min/max index scan. I thought I could keep that value through the $param mechnism, but it is more like macro than a variable.